# How to add <ul> with <a> link into a textarea as simple text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to add links with an `<a>` tag based on user input.

**HTML**

```
<div id="linkRef">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default link-list">Aggiungi un link</button>
  <ul class="main_ul">
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="linkData">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.link-list', function() {
  $("#linkRef").on("DOMSubtreeModified", updateTree);
  $('.main_ul').append(
    $('<li><div class="form-group"><input  placeholder="Dai un nome al link...." class="link_name form-control" type="text"></div><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="inserisci il link..." class="form-control" type="text"></div></li>')
  );
});

function updateTree() {
   var myLinks = $("#linkRef ul");
   $("#linkData textarea").val(myLinks.html() + "\n");
 }

$("#linkRef").on("DOMSubtreeModified", updateTree);
$("#linkRef").on('keyup', '.form-group input', updateTree);
```

The above inserts the added list but it inserts the inputs and buttons and all the html in it too, yet not the actual values, i didn't insert the `<a>` code as i was trying to work out the basic first.

The output within the textarea that I am expecting would be:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <a href="www.example.com">Example</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="www.example2.com">Example2</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I made a [JsFiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/1wt3ttqc/10/)

And this is [another JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44yb96Lb/167/) for another case I had and I was trying to work this new question out based on that but i didn't manage it

Comment: check my answer below. let me know if it works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it:

```
<div id="myList">
  <ul>
    <li><button class="btn btn-default ul-appending">+ Node</button>      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="listData">
  <textarea col="10" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>


$('body').on('click', 'button.ul-appending', function() {
    $(this).parent().append(
    $('<ul class="main_ul">').addClass('newul sortable').append(
    $('<li><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Link title" class="nome_link form-control" type="text"></div><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Link" class="form-control link_url" type="text"></div></li>')
    )
    );
});

$('body').on('click', 'button.removeThis', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
});

function updateTree() {
   $("#listData textarea").text('<li><a href="' + $("#myList input.link_url").val() + '">' + $("#myList input.nome_link").val() + '</a></li>');
 }

$("#myList").on("DOMSubtreeModified", updateTree);
$("#myList").on('keyup', 'input', updateTree);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44yb96Lb/208/)

Answer (score 4):

as far as i know you **cannot** add HTML to a **textarea**

instead you could use an editable div ( that behaves like a textarea )

example : `<div class="texthere" contenteditable="true"></div>`

and also use `outerHtml` so you get also the `<ul></ul>`

plus. i don't see any `a` in your `.main ul` html ( ?? )

see [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1wt3ttqc/12/) or snippet below

```js
$('body').on('click', 'button.link-list', function() {
 $("#linkRef").on("DOMSubtreeModified", updateTree);
  $('.main_ul').append(
    $('<li><div class="form-group"><input  placeholder="Dai un nome al link...." class="link_name form-control" type="text"></div><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="inserisci il link..." class="form-control" type="text"></div></li>')
    );
});

function updateTree() {
  var myLinks = $("#linkRef ul");
   $("#linkData .texthere").html(myLinks.prop("outerHTML") + "\n");
 }

$("#linkRef").on("DOMSubtreeModified", updateTree);
$("#linkRef").on('keyup', '.form-group input', updateTree);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

input {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.margin-top-20 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="linkRef">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default link-list">Aggiungi un link</button>
  <ul class="main_ul">
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="linkData">

<div class="texthere" contenteditable="true"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: i cannot use a div, because i need to send the value of the textarea to the server via php. I give you a hint (will add it to the question), this is another JsFiddle for another case I had, i was trying to work it out based on that actually http://jsfiddle.net/44yb96Lb/167/

Comment: sorry. as i said in my answer. you cannot add html inside a textarea ( change html of a textarea ) it will appear only as text

Comment: Did you see the jsfiddle i pasted in the comment just before?

Comment: yes. and the html inside the textarea ( `<ul class="sortable"><li></li></ul>` ) appears like simple text. but i think you want it to appear like in my example ( except it's a div not a textarea )

Comment: nope, i need to have it as simple text, because I am sending it to the server and then simply doing an echo with that html. The visual bit like you did and I did, it is simply for the user when he's creating the nested list. The textarea will be display none anyway

Answer (score 0):

**I think your html is look like this according to your requirments**

```
 <div id="linkRef">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default link-list">Aggiungi un link</button>
 <span class="main_ul">
 </span>
 </div>

<div id="linkData">
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

**and js is like below to setup textarea**

```
  $('body').on('click', 'button.link-list', function() {
  $("#linkRef").on("DOMSubtreeModified", updateTree);
  $('.main_ul').append(
  $('<ul><li><a href="www.example.com">Example</a></li><li><a href="www.example2.com">Example2</a></li></ul>')
 );
});

  function updateTree() {
  var myLinks = $("#linkRef span");
 $("#linkData textarea").val(myLinks.html() + "\n");
 }

 $("#linkRef").on("DOMSubtreeModified", updateTree);
  $("#linkRef").on('keyup', '.form-group input', updateTree);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('body').on('click', 'button.link-list', function() {
 $("#linkRef").on("DOMSubtreeModified", updateTree);
  $('.main_ul').append(
    $('<li><div class="form-group"><input  placeholder="Dai un nome al link...." class="link_name form-control" type="text"></div><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="inserisci il link..." class="inser_link form-control" type="text"></div></li>')
    );
});

function updateTree() {
  var myLinks = $("#linkRef ul li .link_name");
  var myinserLinks = $("#linkRef ul li .inser_link");
   $("#linkData textarea").val(myLinks.val() + "\n" + myinserLinks.val());
 }

$("#linkRef").on("DOMSubtreeModified", updateTree);
$("#linkRef").on('keyup', '.form-group input', updateTree);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

input {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.margin-top-20 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="linkRef">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default link-list">Aggiungi un link</button>
  <ul class="main_ul">
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="linkData">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```