# Detect links in textarea and input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to allow users to put hyperlinks inside this `textarea` or in `input` and them to be clickable using AngularJS, JavaScript:

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <textarea id="obs" class="sigma-form-simple-search-input large-size" rows="5"
              ng-model="commandeHdr.obs" ng-change="hasChanges.parameter=true"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the hyperlinks to be clickable directly inside the textarea? Or do you process it after it is submitted?

Comment: Directly in the textarea in the real time if it is possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add <ul> with <a> link into a textarea as simple text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140766/how-to-add-ul-with-a-link-into-a-textarea-as-simple-text)

Comment: You can't place any 'Active Link' inside a textarea/input.

Comment: +1  to what Akash Shrivastava said, although you could have a div with [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/contenteditable) instead, although you would need to wrap the link manually inside an `a` tag

Comment: @keff please upvote instead of `+1`. :D

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: What you are looking for is a WYSIWYG editor. For example: https://ckeditor.com/

Comment: I would add a preview, maybe a div below the text-area, where the content gets rendered when value changes, or as Matt says, take a look into some editor.

Comment: This is an example editor, for AngularJS, take a look http://textangular.com/

Comment: Copy and paste my code and I think I have done what you looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am done this for you using this simple technique, I will create an empty Div and then fill it with links which is generated from a TextArea separated each "text link" by a semicolon,

The only thing I didn't do for you is to apply some CSS to style our link as text, I am sure you can do that, it's an easy task.

like this test1.com;test2.com;test3.com, in this case we have 3 websites but they are in text mode, here is how I did this for you:

```
<div id="container" class="col-md-12 form-group">
  <div id="navi" class="col-md-9">
    <textarea id="obs" class="sigma-form-simple-search-input large-size" 
              rows="5" ng-model="commandeHdr.obs"
              ng-change="hasChanges.parameter=true" cols="100" rows="10">
        test1.com;test2.com;test3.com
    </textarea>

    <div id="links">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

here is my Javascript for doing this task...

```
<script>
    // get your textarea
    var ts = document.getElementById("obs");
    // get our empty div
    var linksDiv = document.getElementById("links");
    // remove any empty space
    var urls = ts.value.trim();
    // split our links by ;
    var urlsArr = urls.split(';');
    // get back all new item in original posision, index 3 will be in 1 so I will revese they array...
    urlsArr.reverse();
    //Cleaned from space....
    ts.value = urlsArr;
    // our links will be hold here
    var links = '';
    // for all links we will add
    // ID if you need
    // Class so we can posision all links by CSS
    for (var i in urlsArr) {
        links = "<a class='genlinks' id = '"+i+"' href="+urlsArr[i]+">"+urlsArr[i]+";</a>" + links;
    }
    // now update our div
    linksDiv.innerHTML = links;
</script>
```

And a simple CSS you need is

```
<style>
    #container {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
    }
    #links {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top:3px;
        left: 18px;
    }
    #links {
        z-index: 5;
    }
</style>
```

Please let me know if your problem didn't solve. happy coding.

This is the entire HTML file that I had used.

```
<html>  
<head>
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>awatitwork</title>

    <style>
        #container {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: relative;
        }
        #links {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top:3px;
            left: 18px;
        }
        #links {
            z-index: 5;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" class="col-md-12 form-group">
  <div id="navi" class="col-md-9">
    <textarea id="obs" class="sigma-form-simple-search-input large-size" rows="5" ng-model="commandeHdr.obs" ng-change="hasChanges.parameter=true" cols="100" rows="10">
        test1.com;test2.com;test3.com
    </textarea>

    <div id="links">
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // get your textarea
    var ts = document.getElementById("obs");
    // get our empty div
    var linksDiv = document.getElementById("links");
    // remove any empty space
    var urls = ts.value.trim();
    // split our links by ;
    var urlsArr = urls.split(';');
    // get back all new item in original posision, index 3 will be in 1 so I will revese they array...
    urlsArr.reverse();
    //Cleaned from space....
    ts.value = urlsArr;
    // our links will be hold here
    var links = '';
    // for all links we will add
    // ID if you need
    // Class so we can posision all links by CSS
    for (var i in urlsArr) {
        links = "<a class='genlinks' id = '"+i+"' href="+urlsArr[i]+">"+urlsArr[i]+";</a>" + links;
    }
    // now update our div
    linksDiv.innerHTML = links;
</script>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, but you insert in the textarea automaticaly, if it's not splited by ; that will not be solved. I create another form that contain a paragraph <p>, I change the input to a paragraph

Comment: @imaneBlh, Well I just answered what you asked for, as you see I created a simple system for your URLs which is every URL MUST be separated by ; you can use any other character. I know this is not a good chose for a website but I hoped that I helped what you need. it's better to create a list for them.

Answer (score 0):

The only allowed content of `<textarea>` elements is text.

From the Docs:

> ## `<textarea>` Technical summary
>
> ```
> Permitted content:    Text
>
> Tag omission:         None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.
> ```

For more information, see

- [MDN HTML Reference - `<textarea>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)